Static not loaded when django project deployed
I'm trying to deply my django site, and I did to my ip address, but when I load page online it doesn't load static files. I tried changing different settings on a server and on django files, but I'm out of ideas. I would appreciate a pair of fresh eyes.
Please note that I followed this tutorial (https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-django-with-postgres-nginx-and-gunicorn-on-ubuntu) and everything went well as explained in tutorial, apart from loading static files. When I tested port :8000, static was loaded.
for sites-available I did this:
sudo nano /etc/nginx/sites-available/django-site
Output:
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name xx.xx.xxx.xx; #my ip address

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    location /static/ {
        alias /home/muser/django-site/staticfiles/;
    }

    location / {
        include proxy_params;
        proxy_pass http://unix:/run/gunicorn.sock;
    }
}

this is settings.py
STATIC_URL = 'static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
        os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
]

#media
MEDIA_URL = 'media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = BASE_DIR / 'media'

It might be that this is all correct, but it might be that urls aren't set up properly. So please see urls.py
urlpatterns = i18n_patterns(
    path(_('admin/'), admin.site.urls),
    path('rosetta/', include('rosetta.urls')),
    path('', include('my_app.urls', namespace='my_app')),
)
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL,document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL,document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)

Any ideas what I did wrong? Thanks in advance!
EDIT
When I was setting up limited user I created host and user, host is called django-server, and I added ip adress.
127.0.1.1 ubuntu-4gb-nbg1 ubuntu-4gb-nbg1
127.0.0.1 localhost
xx.xx.xxx.xx django-server

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1 localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters

When I run: sudo tail -f /var/log/nginx/error.log, I have multiple lines like this;
2024/08/19 21:14:59 [error] 29367#29367: *34 open() "/home/muser/django-project/staticfiles/js/owl.carousel.min.js" failed (13: Permission denied), client: xx.xx.xxx.xx, server: xx.xx.xxx.xx, request: "GET /static/js/owl.carousel.min.js HTTP/1.1", host: "xx.xx.xxx.xx", referrer: "http://xx.xx.xxx.xx/en/our-story/".
What kind of permission is denied? Why one is calling staticfiles and other static?
Thanks in advance!

You first need to collect static files: manage,py collectstatic. This will put a copy in thee staticfiles.

I did that, I have folder staticfiles with static files.

You are accessing port 80 on your site right? You mention "When I tested port :8000" which makes me think you're accessing the wrong port. Since Nginx is listening on port 80 that's the port you should be making a request on. So you need to access something like http://127.0.0.1 (Replace 127.0.0.1 with the appropriate IP address)

@AbdulAzizBarkat , you might be onto something. I don't think I set up anywhere port 80, but I did set up host and ip address. When I was setting up host there was 127.0.0.1, which might be what you are referring. I edited the question, and provided the code, should I just delete 127.0.0.1 or?

"I don't think I set up anywhere port 80" look at your Nginx configuration that has listen 80;... If you're still hitting some other port (The port used by Gunicorn? The port of one of the workers spun up by Gunicorn?) What's the point of your Nginx setup? Just hit your website on port 80 does it work? Currently you're probably accessing http://someip:8000 or potentially http://django-server:8000 change that to http://someip orhttp://django-server and check

@AbdulAzizBarkat oh... that is where I used alias for static. I did put my ip adress there server_name xx.xx.xxx.xx;, I just putted Xs to hide my ip. Unless I need to change server name to my actual server name, it should work, but that wasn't stated in tutorial that needs to be changed. But still doesn't make sense, my site and django/python code works, just doesn't load static files.

I'm not accessing http://someip:8000 nor http://django-server:8000. I'm accessing http://my-ip. port 8000 is deleted as stated in tutorial sudo ufw delete allow 8000. When I go to my ip, website is loaded, just doesn't load static files, which means that I don't have css files loaded.

when I run: sudo tail -f /var/log/nginx/error.log, I have multiple lines like this; 2024/08/19 21:14:59 [error] 29367#29367: *34 open() "/home/muser/django-project/staticfiles/js/owl.carousel.min.js" failed (13: Permission denied), client: xx.xx.xxx.xx, server: xx.xx.xxx.xx, request: "GET /static/js/owl.carousel.min.js HTTP/1.1", host: "xx.xx.xxx.xx", referrer: "http://xx.xx.xxx.xx/en/our-story/". What kind of permission is denied?

you use static in setting, but you add staticfiles in nginx conf.
server {
    ...
    location /static/ {
        # alias /home/muser/django-site/staticfiles/;
        alias /home/muser/django-site/static/;
    }
    ...
}


No, their STATIC_ROOT setting points to the staticfiles directory so that should be fine.

My suggestion is to change the name of the folder where ALL THE STATIC FILES WILL BE COLLECTED using the collectstatic command to static and the base static folder that all apps use to staticfiles or any other name you prefer like this:
STATIC_URL = 'static/'
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
        os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles'),
]

and then this should work and all your static files will be served, of course leave all configurations of nginx and gunicorn as is.

This doesn't really make sense, if collectstatic collects all the files into the static directory why would you configure Nginx to server the staticfiles directory instead? The idea behind collectstatic is to put all of the static files in one single location.

yes that's exactly what i said collectstatic will collect all static files into one folder, what i proposed is to change the name of this folder from staticfiles to simply static like shown above in the answer
